Can informal fallacies be considered weak inductive arguments?
Can informal fallacies be considered (weak) inductive arguments?

If they can, then does not that mean they are actually not fallacies (because an inductive argument is a reliable form of reasoning)?

If they cannot, then how does one distinguish an informal fallacy from a (weak) inductive argument?


For example, if one says "X is true, since everyone believes it", does he necessarily commit an Ad Populum fallacy? Is there a possibility he is actually making a weak inductive argument?

Edited for clarification :
Informal fallacies include the Ad Populum Fallacy, Ad Hominem Fallacy. These are fallacies of deductive logic.

Can an argument making an Ad Populum or Ad Hominem fallacy be considered to be actually an inductive argument?

How does one distinguish whether the argument is meant to be a deductive argument (and thus fallacious) or an inductive argument?



An Informal fallacy is an incorrect argument.

Having pondered this, my own two cents are that an informal fallacy is not a weak inductive argument, but a fallacious deductive argument. However, it still seems to be true to me that the same statements can either denote a fallacious deductive argument, or a weak inductive argument. It is not clear for me how to distinguish between the two cases.

Might want to update the question than as Mauro just gave you the answer, though as a comment.

I think you’re onto something but it could use some clarification. Can you define or explain what a weak inductive argument is, in the post? Is it a hypothesis which is meant to be revised?

@JuliusHamilton Added a clarification in the post (I have used the term "weak" in "weak inductive argument" in a colloquial way, meaning something like an inductive argument whose premises guarantee its conclusion with low probability. It is not necessary to use the term "weak" for my question, so I've omitted it in the clarification )

It looks like a terminological issue with a pragmatic twist.
I propose to treat the adjective "ad populum" as a neutral term describing the nature of the argumentation.
Then we may have

ad populum fallacies

and

ad populum inductive arguments

as full phrases that include the evaluation of the argumentation's validity.

I have developed this idea in the course of a conversation with ChatGPT. The link has more details how we have arrived at this consensus.

+1 for being pro-AI and out in the open about it.

@JuliusHamilton Thank you. I have been repeatedly put down on this forum for engaging with AI as philosophical partner.

I usually find that people who discuss fallacy are merely out to dispute the truth of a claim, while not offering a proper explanation of their own position. What fallacy am I committing if I say that "I believe 'x' and that millions of people also believe it, when x="eat s*** 50 million flies cant be wrong ""? you cant just reply with "50 million flies can be wrong" you must explain the difference between why humans would NOT do that, and the reason why flies DO that. Otherwise you are simply stating that you know what it means to call upon the name of something called a fallacy "ad populum fallacy" hahahahaha its just another term for "I am in my second year of a philosophy degree debate me, I am superior". Then people have to go and research that particular subject but unless you explain what YOU mean by "ad populum fallacy" then you are guilty of mere sophism and plagiarism. Explain and expand your arguments, dont just rely on convenient names for logical truth
To answer the question. It is neither. It is usually an argument from a position of ignorance. Not having the full facts. However I cannot recall a single solitary debate when anyone was in possession of the full facts so I dont agree that there is a fallacy. If anyone in the history of the human race had full possession of the facts when making a complicated argument, I would be very surprised indeed
You only have to look at a complicated book such as Mind and Brain, by Ted Honderich, to realise that yes there is truth in it, but not everything he wrote could be true, because nobody really understands the correlation between what we call brain chemistry and mind. You could probably list a 1000 fallacies but arguing the truth is different to naming a fallacy

The problem with calling fallacies is that often enough you're just saying "I refute your claim of certainty because you don't have the full facts". Which is a valid objection, but if they slightly modified that to "I'm 99% certain [same claim]" you'd be back to square one either trying to push the 99% lower to a weak inductive argument or actually tackling the claim and it's internal logic. So beyond a short shock moment and a google search, using those fallacies isn't usually the terminating argument that people think it is but more of a technical point.

You unfortunately mix and confuse a lot of terminology here.
Like deductive arguments somewhat follow the form of making premises (that are supposed to be certain) and from these premises you draw a conclusion.
For example:
All Orcs have nose rings
Zorc is an Orc 
Therefore Zorc has a nose ring

Now such an argument would be valid, if the conclusion would indeed follow from the premises. So in other words if the premises were ACTUALLY true would the conclusion also HAVE TO be true? And yeah in that case if all Orcs do have nose rings and if Zorc is among that group than Zorc would have a nose ring. Now for all that we know Orcs don't exist and not all Orc depictions show them with a nose ring, so the argument is valid but the premises are not true. So in technical terms a (deductive) argument that is both valid and has true premises (and in consequence a true conclusion) would be called sound. So it is valid but not sound.
Now if an argument does fail to adhere to the deductive form (usually making them invalid) you'd call that a (formal) fallacy. Idk:
Zorc has a nose ring 
Zorc is an Orc
Therefore strawberry icecream is tasty

Now the conclusion is in no way shape or form even related to the premises hence that argument is invalid.
A little more tricky are informal fallacies where you give the impression of a valid argument but the conclusion still doesn't follow from the premises.
Idk:
A star is a luminous spheroid of plasma held together by self-gravity.
Taylor Swift is a star
Therefor Taylor Swift is a luminous spheroid of plasma held together by self-gravity.

While that appears to be valid (if that would be what a star is and if taylor swift would be a star, then this conclusion would make sense), a cautious observer might figure out that while they use the same word, the two premises actually use two different definitions of the word star, hence the conclusion does not actually follow from the premise despite the form looking really promising. Hence an informal fallacy.
Now on the other end you have inductive reasoning where you try to generate a rule from a serious of examples.
The proportion Q of the sample has attribute A.
Assuming the sample is a representative subset of the population
Therefore, the proportion Q of the population has attribute A.

Now these are no longer claims of certainty so the terms "valid/invalid" no longer apply, because the conclusion doesn't HAVE TO follow from the premises. Though such arguments could still be weaker or stronger compared to each other based on the actual probabilities of these assumptions. So idk larger sample sizes and multiple iterations of the experiment might make such arguments stronger than already generalizing from the first example. So if the argument is strong and the premises are true (probably more like: are very likely to be true) you'd call that cogent, while if the premises are not true or the argument wasn't strong to begin with you'd call that uncogent.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning#/media/File:Argument_terminology_used_in_logic_(en).svg
Now what you likely wanted to hint at is that the entire branch of that tree referring to inductive reasoning is technically fallacies in terms of deductive reasoning.
Because unlike your claim in the question:

If they can, then does not that mean they are actually not fallacies (because an inductive argument is a reliable form of reasoning)?

These are not reliable. Just because something works 99% of the time does not mean it will work the next time you try it. You can't rely on that particular outcome, it's just very likely. Now usually that distinction is often ignored and overlooked because we can't be certain of pretty much anything so "close enough" is often treated as "reliable", but that's not technically correct.
So because you can't rely on any of the premises, you also can't reliably follow any conclusion from them either hence they are deductively speaking a fallacy.
Now as that isn't particularly useful in everyday life you might still think of strong and cogent arguments as somewhat valid-ish and would apply a modified fallacy definition to the weak and uncogent arguments so that colloquially they might overlap.
Though technically you all of them would be fallacies.
So I guess what you really tried to hint at is the fact that the subset of cogent inductive arguments which are deductive fallacies are actually somewhat useful in everyday life and unlike uncogent and weak inductive arguments not necessarily considered a fallacy.
And they can avoid being a fallacy with one simple trick: Just not assume they are a matter of certainty, but being aware that they are just induction, that no matter how strong they are there is still a rest value of uncertainty and to not ignore that.
So some subset of deductive fallacies could be considered cogent inductive arguments, which might not end up being grouped with the (INDUCTIVE) fallacies.
Update:

Can an argument making an Ad Populum or Ad Hominem fallacy be considered to be actually an inductive argument?


How does one distinguish whether the argument is meant to be a deductive argument (and thus fallacious) or an inductive argument?

Well they follow a certain form. Oversimplified deductive arguments take a general rule and apply it to a particular example, while inductive arguments start from a particular example and construct a general rule from that.
So suppose Alice is making an argument about the seriousness of  climate change and that we should act now and Bob tries to counter that by:
Liars must not be trusted
Alice lied once about her weight / (read: Alice is a liar)
Alice must not be trusted

Then this would be an ad hominem fallacy, rather than engaging with the actually argument Bob attacks Alice as a person. But form wise he's doing it with a valid but unsound deductive argument not with an inductive one. He's making the case "if A then B; A=true; therefore B". The inductive ad hominem argument would rather be something like "Once a liar, always a liar" or something like:
Alice made a statement
Alice's statement was a lie
All of Alice's statements are lies

And lying and the doubt cast on a statement because of that, is already close to an argument. But you could go even further in the domain of non-sequitur (does not follow) and idk argue that the other person's argument is invalid because they wear weird socks or whatnot. So if there is no relation between demeaning the other person and the argument itself, it won't even serve as an inductive argument either, but is simply bad.
So ad hominem fallacies are a broad range of problematic arguments that can be inductive arguments but don't have to be.
Now ad populum fallacies are a tricky. I see where you'd go with that, arguing that a plurality of proponents proves a case is very similar to more data = stronger inductive argument. Where you could argue that failing the conclusive certainty still makes for a strong inductive claim if you rephrase it like that. But it's also pretty important what the actual argument is and whether numbers matter.
Like idk if someone speaks for the world famous "silent majority" (aka makes a claim of which they assert it's supported by a majority, which realistically hasn't taken a stance either way yet) and they provide data from an actual majority, then this is a strong claim.
While if you make an opinion poll on people about the question via gravity exists... Well even if you asked every single human on earth, that would appear to be conclusive evidence before you realize it isn't because humans opinions on gravity don't relate to the existence of natural phenomena. Gravity would also exist if people don't think it does (it might get you into problems how you would think of something that you think doesn't exist, but that's not relevant here).
So again it could be something that you can rephrase as an inductive argument, but there are also a lot of options where it's just a bad argument.

I award this answer a bounty as a way to show appreciation for schooling me with the correct terminology to be used. I have added a clarification in the OP however and it would be great if you could answer, following the clarification.

As stated or implied by other answers and comments, I think we can pull some informal fallacies out of the trash can if we clean them up in two ways: (1) At its core, ensuring a legitimate connection between premise and conclusion; and (2) Diluting the strength of the conclusion to honestly reflect the strength of the premises and their level of connection with the conclusion.  For instance, by changing, "Therefore, for sure X" to a conditional probability such as, "Therefore, X becomes more likely," some informal fallacies are rescued (which to your question, can also include rescuing deductive flaws into valid inductive arguments).
I also think that people tend to use a kind of "shorthand" in everyday speech, and if we are too analytical, we might label certain things "fallacies" when in reality, we have missed the real point!  Further, a lot of quippy sayings may technically be tautologies or paradoxes on the surface, and yet sometimes they do express real meaning underneath; it's simply a clever and succinct use of words (e.g., Matthew 10:39).
For instance, here are a couple of sample salvagable informal fallacies I would see:

Ad hominem: "Bob claims he's running late because his car broke down; but he frequently has excuses, and almost all of them turn out to be false in the end."  If the intended conclusion is, "Therefore, Bob is totally lying this time," then that's a fallacy; but if it's only, "Bob is probably lying, given his recent false excuses; but without more evidence, who knows," then I don't see any fallacy with that.  There is a legitimate inductive connection between his overall reliability and how we ought to think of his latest excuse.
Appeal to ignorance: (Tornado barrelling toward barn) "The barn's a goner!"  "No, you don't know that for sure!"  That's okay because the conclusion is simply that the barn might not be a goner, rather than appealing to ignorance to conclude that it is certainly not.  For all you know, the tornado may swerve before hitting the barn.
Red herring: "Give me one good reason why you disagree with that."  "My reason is, the pizza's out of the oven, let's eat!"  In this case, the conclusion is not about the argument itself, but about whether we're focusing too much energy on this debate relative to the other things of life.  But if being too analytical, someone might misunderstand and reply, "What in the world does pizza have to do with it?!"
Ad populum: "Most people say they feel like they have an immaterial 'soul,' and so this is evidence that humans are more than mere matter."  I don't think that's a deductive fallacy; it's simply using the expressed experience of most people as inductive evidence toward the conclusion.  Whereas if the argument were, "Most people said it, therefore it must be true," then that's a clear fallacy.

But I'd also say that other informal fallacies are unsalvagable, such as when they are self-defeating (e.g., begging the question), or when there is no legitimate connection between the premise and conclusion (e.g., using abusive language to strengthen the person's position).
